# ¿Se dice "ellos tocan flautas" o "ellos tocan flauta"?

Tags: plurales, argentina

En [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/5096/768) se puede encontrar el siguiente ejemplo:

> Vio a una mujer y a un hombre tocando flautas traversas.

Mi impresión inicial fue que el plural en *flautas* era incorrecto, siendo la versión correcta:

> Vio a una mujer y a un hombre tocando flauta traversa.

- ¿Por qué dice la [RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=WNwv1L8sYD6hHZwATa) que el plural es correcto? ¿O es un regionalismo argentino?
- ¿Acaso uno dice "*mis hijos tocan pianos*", *"nosotros sabemos tocar guitarras"*, etc.?

---

Hay flautas traversas/transversas en varias tesituras (desde flauta sopranino, hasta flauta doblecontrabajista). Esa es la única justificación que encontraría para un plural.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La primera conclusión que yo haría de las respuestas dadas hasta el momento es que `tocar flauta` es una expresión regional:

- En España (@makeMonday) se dice solamente `tocar la flauta`
- En Mexico (@José María) y en Argentina (@c.p.) se dan ambas formas: `tocar (la) flauta`

La segunda conclusión que haría es que la expresión `tocar flautas` también está en uso:

- @c.p. cita a la [RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=WNwv1L8sYD6hHZwATa)
- y el visor de n-gramas de Google también [demuestra su uso](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tocar+flautas%2C+tocar+flauta&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctocar%20flautas%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctocar%20flauta%3B%2Cc0):

  - `"y luego empezaron á tocar flautas y tocaron el son de Hun-ahpu-mico."` (Las historias del origen de los indios de esta provincia de Guatemala -- Popol-vuh)
  - `"Son músicos de su propio genio, y como en varias partes de esta Historia consta, son muy aficionados a tocar flautas, que ellos se fabrican y otros muchos instrumentos;"` (Noticias musicales en los cronistas de la Venezuela de los siglos XVI-XVIII -- Mariantonia Palacio)
  - `"Salir al aire a tocar flautas es acercarse al mar, al olivar o, como hace el sujeto lírico de Junto al lago, al hermoso trigal"` (Antonio Colinas o la escritura como aventura circular -- Guy Merlín Nana Tadoun)
  - `"Era también costumbre entre ellos la de cantar en los funerales y tocar flautas."` (Diccionario de teología -- Bergier)

En respuesta a la pregunta original de @c.p.: creo que esta lista del visor de n-gramas es especialmente esclarecedora y que justifica afirmar que la cita tomada de la [RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=WNwv1L8sYD6hHZwATa) es simplemente un ejemplo de uso regional de la forma `tocar flautas`.

---

**Edición anterior**

El visor de n-gramas de Google muestra en este [enlace](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tocar+la+flauta%2Ctocar+las+flautas%2Ctocar+flauta%2Ctocar+flautas&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctocar%20la%20flauta%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctocar%20las%20flautas%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctocar%20flauta%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctocar%20flautas%3B%2Cc0) que la forma más frecuente es `tocar la flauta`.

Google también muestra que la forma `tocar flautas` solo aparece [7 veces](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22tocar+flautas%22&oq=%22tocar+flautas%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.7558j0j4&client=ubuntu-browser&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22tocar+flautas%22+site%3a.ar) en páginas argentinas frente a unas [134000 ocurrencias](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22tocar+flautas%22+site%3A.ar&oq=%22tocar+flautas%22+site%3A.ar&aqs=chrome..69i57.2744j0j1&client=ubuntu-browser&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22tocar+la+flauta%22+site%3a.ar) de la forma `tocar la flauta`.

Comment: Muy objetiva respuesta. De hecho yo prefiero "tocar flauta". No sé por qué, pero "tocar la flauta" se me hace como "tocar la flauta de la escuelita". No puedo explicarlo, pero tengo el prejuicio de que omitiendo el artículo uno habla de hacer música seriamente. Pero es sólo un prejuicio.

Comment: @c.p., también he encontrado que ambas formas, `tocar flauta` y `tocar la flauta`, aparecen en títulos de libros de música, pero no he encontrado ningún título con contenga `flauta traversa`.

Comment: En España, al menos, diríamos *flauta travesera*, no *traversa*. El DRAE solo recoge esta forma, de hecho, aunque no descarto que en otros países se use la forma *flauta traversa*.

Answer (score 3):

> Hay flautas traversas/transversas en varias tesituras (desde flauta
>   sopranino, hasta flauta doblecontrabajista). Esa es la única
>   justificación que encontraría para un plural.

A mi me parece que ésta suposición tuya es de hecho la respuesta correcta. A mi parecer suena muy raro utilizar el plural de algún instrumento aún para referirse a dos sujetos tocando los mismos.

La única manera de interpretar ese plural para "flauta", sería la variedad de las mismas, es decir, siguiendo con el mismo ejemplo, uno de los sujetos podría haber estado tocando la flauta trasversa sopranino y el otro sujeto la flauta traversa doblecontrabajista, por lo tanto sería muy ilógico hacer mención exacta de ambos nombres de dichas flautas para una oración que no requiere tanto detalle.

Por lo menos en México es inusual utilizar el plural para una oración como la del ejemplo. Suponiendo que el ejemplo hablase sólamente de flautas, sin entrar en detalle de su tipo, usariamos: `Vió a una mujer y a un hombre tocando (la) flauta.`

Answer (score 2):

Según mi punto de vista `tocando flautas traversas` está en plural porque cada uno está tocando su flauta traversa. Es algo raro (o no es normal), pero creo que es totalmente válido. En España al menos se suele decir:

> Juan y María estaban tocando la guitarra.

Dicho así puede dar pie a una confusión. Parece que Juan y María están tocando la misma guitarra, pero por lo general se entiende que cada uno toca una diferente. Si ponemos ese ejemplo como la frase que preguntas, quedaría:

> Juan y María estaban tocando (las) guitarras.

Como digo, me resulta una frase válida, a pesar de que suene muy extraña.

P.D.: La frase que dices que te parece la correcta, creo que también lo es. Mi única pega a esa frase es que en España se añadiría el `la`, como en la primera frase que he puesto arriba.

Este es mi punto de vista, porque creo que esta pregunta es más sobre eso que sobre una forma "correcta" de escribir ese caso específico ;)

Answer (score 2):

Realmente no se dice de ninguna de las dos maneras. La manera correcta sería:

Vio a una mujer y a un hombre tocando **la** flauta travesera (o traversa)

Es exactamente el mismo caso que "tocar el piano" o "tocar la guitarra". Nadie dice:

"mis hijos tocan pianos" o "mis hijos tocan piano"

"nosotros sabemos tocar guitarras" o "nosotros sabemos tocar guitarra"

se dice:

Mis hijos tocan el piano

Nosotros sabemos tocar la guitarra

En todos los casos se usa la expresión artículo + nombre ("la flauta") para indicar que nos referimos al instrumento en general, no a un objeto en concreto. "Mis hijos tocan guitarras" significaría, en correcto castellano, que mis hijos están en contacto con objetos que llamamos "guitarra", como si dijéramos "Mis hijos tocan paredes".

Comment: Sí, me parece correcto. Lo que no me queda claro es por qué es necesario el artículo. Es decir, "Mis hijos tocan guitarras" es definitivamente incorrecto, pero lo que ahí me suena incorrecto es sólo el plural.

Comment: Compare: "- ¿Y usted que hace? - Soy músico, toco en la Orquesta Filarmónica de *X*. Toco contrabajo." Esa conversación se me hace normal. En cambio "Toco el contrabajo" suena muy raro: no hay sólo un contrabajo en una filarmónica.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui hay dos conceptos distintos que se están mezclando, tanto en el post original como en casi todas las respuestas. Una cosa es "tocar la flauta", va todo junto y se refiere a un tipo de actividad completo. Otra es "tocar una flauta", se refiere a una acción puntual y aun instrumento concreto.

En la frase original, `'Vio a una mujer y a un hombre tocando flautas traversas.'`, se refiere a unas personas que estaban tocando música con unas flautas concretas, las que tenían en las manos.

En la frase `'Juan toca la flauta'`, hablamos de que Juan puede tocar cualquier flauta. Y en `'Juan y María tocan la flauta'` se refiere a que están tocando música de flauta, los instrumentos en sí podrían ser cualquier flauta. Lo importante es que están realizando la actividad "tocar la flauta", no que estén usando unas flautas (aunque al final sea lo mismo).

La diferencia es muy sutil, lo sé, y en la mayoría de los casos irrelevante, pero explica por qué ambas formas son correctas (artículo+singular o indefinido elíptico+plural) y otras no.

Comment: ¿Y que diferencia habría entre (1) `Vio a una mujer y a un hombre tocando flautas traversas`, (2) `Vio a una mujer y a un hombre tocando **las** flautas traveseras` y (3) `Vio a una mujer y a un hombre tocando **unas** flautas traveseras`?

Comment: La (1) y la (3) son exactamente iguales e intercambiables. La (2) indicaría referencia a unas flautas traveseras particulares, ya mencionadas en el texto.

Una variante de la (2), con _la flauta travesera_, en singular, se referiría a la acción <tocar la flauta travesera>, de ahí la no-conjugación del complemento directo.

Comment: por curiosidad, ¿has escuchado alguna vez en España usar la expresión `tocar flauta`?

Comment: En singular, nunca.

Answer (score 0):

La forma correcta depende si son distintos tipos de flauta. O sea, si una flauta es de un tipo y otra de otro tipo. or ejemplo, podemos tener una guitarra normal y una eléctrica. En ese caso, se tocan las guitarras ya que atribuye el plural al instrumento. Para contestar la pregunta debemos saber si el instrumento tiene un plural (Son diferentes flautas) o es singular. Si fuese singular, (Hasta donde se, solo exita un tipo de flauta) entonces se diria ellos tocan la flauta. Pero si fuesen plural (i.e. distintos tipos de flauta) entonces ellos tocan las flautas. La forma correcta radican en la misma palabra e es independiente del resto de la oración. Me gradué de Literatura Comparada, o sea, de escribir propiamente y criticar lo escrito.